# Is a Four or five way electric motor possible?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Okay, I don't know if I correctly stated my question but ill lay it out for you. You have a simple electric motor that you may find in one of a kids toys. It is run via an *electromagnet* that when you provide *electricity* it spins a rod in the middle. I have also seen a *double-sided* motor in a Nerf gun I pulled apart and I could understand that working but what if there were to be **four spinning rods**? Wouldn't introducing another magnetic field disturb the mechanical process?
I have already checked various sites and search engines and couldn't find a relevant source.

Comment: What I think you want to look up is "multipole motor". The answer is that electric motors can have many different numbers of poles in them.

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to have them any size, the images and things that I saw are all of a relatively large size. If you could provide a link that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, small multipole DC motors are available. four-pole 12 volt motors were used as start motors in some models of Yamaha motorcycles in the 1980's as a way of getting more power out of a smaller motor size.

Comment: And those do get relatively small?

Comment: a four pole start motor is about 3 inches in diameter and 6 inches long.  I have not seen any smaller than this.